# Http failure during parsing (angular/java)

Tags: java, angular

Hi guys im working on an angular project with a java (spring boot) backend and sql server for database,i have a method that uses "Get" but im getting the following error:

```
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/admin/allcompanies/02ff0785-3739-4f8d-b77f-eff6b77954f8"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/admin/allcompanies/02ff0785-3739-4f8d-b77f-eff6b77954f8"
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onL…, text: "[{"id":2,"name":"Comp2","password":"comp2","email"…lcompanies/02ff0785-3739-4f8d-b77f-eff6b77954f8"}"}
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Ive tried adding {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})/text/blob but im getting a compliation error

```
error TS2322: Type '"arraybuffer"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

code snippits:
relevant service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AdminService {

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) { }

public getAllCompanies(): Observable<Company[]>{
  return this.client.get<Company[]>("http://localhost:8080/admin/allcompanies/" + sessionStorage.token);
}
```

method component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-get-all-companies',
  templateUrl: './get-all-companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-all-companies.component.css']
})
export class GetAllCompaniesComponent implements OnInit {
  public companies : Company[]=new Array();

  constructor(private client:AdminService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.client.getAllCompanies().subscribe(companies => {
      this.companies=companies;
    });
  }

}
```

my routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
    {path: "admin", component : AdminComponent},
    {path:"home",component:HomeComponent},
    {path:"addcomp",component:AddCompanyComponent},
    {path:"updatecomp",component:UpdateCompanyComponent},
    {path:"deletecomp",component:DeleteCompanyComponent},
    {path:"allcompanies",component:GetAllCompaniesComponent},
    {path:"company",component:GetOneCompanyComponent},
    {path:"", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full"}


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and my backend controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    Map<String, Session> sessionsMap;


    @GetMapping("/allcompanies/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllCompanies(@PathVariable String token) {
        Session session = sessionsMap.get(token);
        if (session != null) {
            // session.setLastAccessed(??);
            AdminFacade facade = (AdminFacade) session.getFacade();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(facade.getAllCompanies());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Unauthorized login");

        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure your response is a valid json? Try validating your json response with a json validator manually to rule that out 2. If you are using responseType as text you should not specify any Observable type in yout http get request. eg.   this.client.get(yourequesturl, { headers: httpOptions , responseType: 'text'})